# DateTime.MinValue and SqlDateTime overflow

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I don't want to validate `txtBirthDate` so I want to pass `DateTime.MinValue` in database.

My code:

```
 if (txtBirthDate.Text == string.Empty)
    objinfo.BirthDate = DateTime.MinValue;
 else
     objinfo.BirthDate =  DateTime.Parse(txtBirthDate.Text);
```

`DateTime.MinValue` return `Date = {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`

I got a  SQL Error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

I understand it but I don't understand why `DateTime.MinValue` returns invalid date time which is unable to insert in database. How to handle this type of situation?

Comment: Define a min-value yourself?

Comment: The message is kind of explaining that to you. The min date time accepted by SQL Server is 1/1/1753 whereas .Net uses 1/1/0001. What do you not understand?

Comment: The logic would suggest to use `DateTime?` in C#, allow the field to accept null in the database and insert `DBNull.Value` in case where `objinfor.BirthDate.HasValue` is `false`. What I mean is that it should reflect the reality. If situation where there is no birth date is acceptable than it should be nullable.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Basically, don't use `DateTime.MinValue` to represent a missing value. You *can't* use `DateTime.MinValue` in a SQL Server DateTime field, as SQL Server has a minimum value of the start of 1753.

Instead, make your `BirthDate` property a `Nullable<DateTime>` (aka `DateTime?`), and set it to `null` when you don't have a value. Also make sure your database field is nullable. Then you just need to make sure that that `null` ends up as a `NULL` value in the database. Exactly how you do that will depend on your data access, which you haven't told us anything about.

Comment: WCF automatically assumes `DateTime.MinValue` if a `DateTime` parameter to your `OperationContract` has been omitted. Furthermore, WCF does not accept `Nullable<T>` parameters. What this means is that in each `OperationContract` you are forced to then do something like `if (myDate < SqlDateTime.MinValue) myDate = SqlDateTime.MinValue;`. Of course, now, you are tightly coupled to the SqlServer. It seems like this conversion should automatically be done by the DBAL, or SqlServer itself when it receives a date < its minimum date. However, it doesn't, thus our options are limited.

Comment: @crush: Well do you have to couple your WCF model and your SQL model together directly? I suspect I'd have a "logical" model which had a `Nullable<DateTime>`, and convert to/from that when I needed to use WCF. Not that I've used WCF much, but it feels like a bad idea for the limitations of WCF to permeate the rest of the model.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Correct me if I'm reading your response wrong. Are you suggesting that the model/DAO be responsible for bounding the minimum value of the `DateTime` as opposed to the Data Access Layer or SqlServer?

Comment: @crush: I'm suggesting that if you want to be able to represent a `Nullable<DateTime>` in your logical model, and WCF doesn't let you do that, then you should fix it as close to the WCF boundary as possible. If there are other aspects of your logical model that SQL Server doesn't let you represent, you should fix *those* as close to the DB boundary as possible. Work with a logical representation for as much of your code as possible, IMO.

Comment: I feel the same way. However, I might ask the OP's question with a specific focus on WCF to see if anyone else has solved this problem in a genius/obvious way. Perhaps, I'm just overlooking something rather simple.

Comment: SQL Server Datetime is indeed min start of 1753, but with sql server 2008 and greater you should be using Datetime2 as then matches up with .Net going back to year of 0001

Answer (score 131):

Very simple avoid using `DateTime.MinValue` use `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue` instead.

Comment: Use `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value` if you want to assign the value in `DateTime?` type field

Answer (score 19):

Well... its quite simple to get a SQL min date

```
DateTime sqlMinDateAsNetDateTime = System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
```

Comment: MinValue is not a DateTime but a SqlDateTime. You need to use MinValue.Value

Answer (score 12):

Although it is an old question, another solution is to use datetime2 for the database column.
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)

Comment: correct.   SQL Server Datetime is indeed min start of 1753, but with sql server 2008 and greater you should be using Datetime2 as then matches up with .Net going back to year of 0001

Comment: Probably the simplest and probably best solution here, assuming the OP can change the database query parameter. As the following link states, new work should use `datetime2`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: this solution still throws the error if the date is less than the sqldatetime minValue but greater than system minValue.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

> Date and time data from January 1, 1753, to December 31, 9999, with an
>   accuracy of one three-hundredth second, or 3.33 milliseconds. Values
>   are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 milliseconds. Stored
>   as two 4-byte integers. The first 4 bytes store the number of days
>   before or after the base date, January 1, 1900. The base date is the
>   system's reference date. Values for datetime earlier than January 1,
>   1753, are not permitted. The other 4 bytes store the time of day
>   represented as the number of milliseconds after midnight. Seconds have
>   a valid range of 0–59.

SQL uses a different system than C# for DateTime values.

You can use your MinValue as a sentinel value - and if it is MinValue - pass null into your object (and store the date as nullable in the DB).

```
if(date == dateTime.Minvalue)
    objinfo.BirthDate = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, **don't** use `DateTime.MinVaue` as a default value.

There are a couple of different `MinValues` out there, depending which environment you are in.

I once had a project, where I was implementing a Windows CE project, I was using the Framework's `DateTime.MinValue` (year 0001), the database `MinValue` (1753) and a UI control `DateTimePicker` (i think it was 1970). So there were at least **3 different MinValues** that were leading to strange behavior and unexpected results. (And I believe that there was even a fourth (!) version, I just do not recall where it came from.).

Use **a nullable database field** and change your value into a `Nullable<DateTime>` instead. Where there is **no valid value** in your code, there should **not** be a value in the database as well. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Here is what you can do. Though there are lot many ways to achieve it.

```
DateTime? d = null;    
if (txtBirthDate.Text == string.Empty)
    objinfo.BirthDate = d;
else
    objinfo.BirthDate =  DateTime.Parse(txtBirthDate.Text);
```

> Note: This will work only if your database datetime column is Allow Null. Else you can define a standard minimum value for     DateTime d.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this function to tryparse

```
public static bool TryParseSqlDateTime(string someval, DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeFormats, out DateTime tryDate)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        tryDate = (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
        System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime sdt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(someval, dateTimeFormats, DateTimeStyles.None, out tryDate))
        {
            try
            {
                sdt = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(tryDate);
                valid = true;
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException ex)
            {

            }
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use DATETIME2 you may find you have to pass the parameter in specifically as DATETIME2, otherwise it may helpfully convert it to DATETIME and have the same issue.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@FirstRegistration",SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = installation.FirstRegistration;
```

Comment: Even after making the field type datetime2 MS SQL is not letting me insert the value. and gives same exception of SQL `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.`

Comment: Well never mind I have handled it manually by value to assign "1753/01/01 12:01:01 AM" now its working fine.

Comment: The database field needs to be DATETIME2 as well as the C# code

Answer (score -7):

use extensions

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime MinValue(this DateTime sqlDateTime)
    {
        return new DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
    }
}


DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Minvalue is {0} ", date.MinValue().ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: This works for me.
return new DateTime(1900, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);