# SQL Server : get max/min possible date without magic numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, magic-numbers

I know that the SQL Server [`date` datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) is defined to have a range of 0001-01-01 to 9999-12-31. Is there any way to obtain those values using T-SQL without the use of magic numbers (e.g. without something like `declare @MaxDate date = '12/31/9999'`)?

Comment: what do you mean with `coerce those values`?

Comment: Obtain, sorry! Poor choice of words - editing momentarily :)

Comment: It still doesn't clarify what you want to do. When do you need to get those values?

Comment: Question is why do you need that?

Comment: The question is as stated - if I wanted a different methodology I would have asked for that instead. My hope is that this could be made type-ambiguous (e.g. `maxof(int)`, `maxof(decimal(3,2))`)

Comment: Alright but still I`m curious.Any reason for the max range of a type?Didnt downvote.

Comment: Here are some questions that might give you some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825893/sql-server-function-to-return-minimum-date-january-1-1753, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157328/datetime-minvalue-and-sqldatetime-overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding max possible date in ms sql server 2005+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548353/finding-max-possible-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Comment: @BobKaufman - yes, exactly!

Comment: @Mihai My purpose is primarily academic... I find the C# analogs (e.g. `DateTime.MinValue`) quite useful, was writing a query that might benefit, and realized I had no idea if they were available. Searching Google yielded no useful results.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can't get the maximum, but I've also just learned that you can't get the minimum either.

You could do this with the datetime type:

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS datetime)
--returns 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

But you can't do it with the date type:

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS date)
--returns Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
--Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.
```

Comment: Too bad. Odd choice, all things considered - the intent is pretty obvious. Seems maximum is [out of reach as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548353/finding-max-possible-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005)...

Answer (score 0):

There is a sort of round about way of getting. But you could do this:

```
DECLARE @dateHighest nvarchar(400), @dateLowest nvarchar(400)

SET @dateHighest = 'powershell.exe ((([System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime]::MaxValue).Value).ToString(\""MM/dd/yyyy\""))'

SET @dateLowest = 'powershell.exe ((([System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime]::MinValue).Value).ToString(\""MM/dd/yyyy\""))'

DECLARE @useTopDate table 
(
    highestDate date
)

DECLARE @useBottomDate table 
(
    lowestDate date
)


INSERT INTO @useBottomDate EXEC xp_cmdshell @dateLowest
INSERT INTO @useTopDate EXEC xp_cmdshell @dateHighest

SELECT TOP 1 * From @useTopDate, @useBottomDate
```

If you need it in a Stored Proc or function you can use it later.

Comment: This would get the CLR min/max, not necessarily what SQL server is configured for.

Comment: @DanField, yep as per the note at the end, but in most cases they should be the same, just not sure of the use case for this by the asker.

Comment: They're not the same for MinValue on a `Datetime` (but they are for a `date`).  It might work better if you chagned your PS to `'powershell.exe (([System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime]::MaxValue...` and MinValue.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310569/what-is-the-significance-of-1-1-1753-in-sql-server

Comment: Editing now as it's a more elegant solution and good to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

So this doesn't work without Magic numbers, but if you need functions (I used hex notation as it's a bit more compact and easier to read for numbers this large)

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(0x2D247f AS BIGINT) AS DATETIME) AS DATE) --, CAST(0x2D247f AS BIGINT)
SELECT CAST(CAST(CAST(0xD1BA AS BIGINT) * -1 AS DATETIME) AS DATE) --, CAST(0xD1BA AS BIGINT) * -1
```

Although, on the lower end, SQL Server will allow 1/1/1:

```
SELECT CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATE)
```

But not negative dates (e.g. BC).